# how to create button shortcuts in vbnet

Tags: vb.net

I tried creating keyboard shortcuts for my buttons.

Here is my code

```
 Private Sub form_main_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If Keys.ControlKey + Keys.N Then
        'btn_add.PerformClick()
        addentry()
    ElseIf Keys.ControlKey + Keys.E Then
        'btn_edit.PerformClick()
        editentry()
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is even when I press other buttons the function is still called. I also tried using form `keydown` property but the result is still the same.

additional info:

- the functions `addentry` and `editentry` will just call the `form_addedit`
- `btn_add` will call for `addentry`
- `btn_edit` will call for `editentry`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `Keys.***` is just an enumeration. Every entry in it is just a number *representing a key code*. So you are currently just adding numbers together.

`Keys.ControlKey` is 17 and `Keys.N` is 78, so you're literally writing:

```
If 17 + 78 Then
```

Which will always return `True` because it's greater than 0.

To do what you ask you must check which key was pressed by checking *the event arguments* (EventArgs) passed to the event.

But since you are using the `KeyPress` event you cannot get the key enumeration out of the event args, so I recommend you to use the `KeyDown` event instead.

```
Private Sub form_main_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Control = True AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.N Then
        addentry()
    ElseIf e.Control = True AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.E Then
        editentry()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks it works. but i can't help to ask why there is a 'ting' sound when i press another keys except those that have shortcuts

Comment: @pwalaako2 : There always is, it's standard to any form. If you add a completely new form to your project and press a random key combination it will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you put an ampersand in the .Text property of the button, Alt+key will fire the button, for example **B&utton1** will fire with Alt+u.

Comment: well i tried that but it kinda messes up the view of my app since my buttons got images on them... and honestly i dont know how it works

Comment: Assuming you mean regular buttons and not toolstrip buttons, If you don't want the text to show at all, add 1 or more blank lines to the text property before the text to push the text out of view.

Comment: well yes regular buttons... ah btw will only "&u" as the text property will fire as alt+u? and also will it disregard the space before the ampersand?

Comment: Yes to both questions.