# Converting a key press to text box in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, keypress

I am currently using Visual Basic 2010 and am making a basic calculator. It should recognize keystrokes from the numpad and treat them like the buttons on my calculator used for numbers and operations. However, I cannot get it to work.

For example, I'd like my program to display the number 4 in the command line when numpad 4 is pressed and am trying to do it like this:

```
    Private Sub BeforeLoad(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, Me.KeyDown
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    If Keys.NumPad4 = True Then
        If (Input AndAlso txtDisplay.Text <> "0") Or Point Then
            txtDisplay.Text += btn4.Text
        Else
            txtDisplay.Text = btn4.Text
            Input = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

However, when I start my program and try to click numpad4, nothing shows up. Any help into this matter would be greatly appreciated. [*Solved*]

My other problem is that the enter button returns a value of '1' on the numpad instead of calculating the answer that I'd like it to.

```
Case Keys.Enter
EnterPress(btnEqual)        

Private Sub EnterPress(btn As Button)
    '# Enter Button
    If txtDisplay.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        CalculateTotals()
        Operation = String.Empty
        Point = False
    End If
End Sub
```

My code in its entirety can be found here: http://pastebin.com/dsMCNy3i

Here is the code to my equals button:

```
    Private Sub Master(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEqual.Click
    If ModOp = True Then
        Num2 = Val(txtDisplay.Text)
        txtDisplay.Text = Num1 Mod Num2
    ElseIf txtDisplay.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        CalculateTotals()
        Operation = String.Empty
        Point = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: have you put a breakpoint in and stepped through your code to see what it is doing?

Comment: Are you using WinForms?

Comment: You cannot subscribe to the `KeyDown` in a method set up for `Form Load`. Recreate the event via the event list and then check `If e.KeyCode = Keys.Numpad4 Then`.

Comment: Here's an answer I gave to a similar question a few weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36662317/3740093

Comment: _@MaCron_ : I don't know what a breakpoint is since I really don't know what I'm doing, so no. _@GibralterTop_ : Yes. _@Visual Vincent_ : Thanks for your answer, however, for some reason that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I've found two solutions to this.

1) Put a '&' symbol before the number in the button's text in the properties window.

2) This code worked for me:

```
    Private Sub Keystrokes(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.NumPad1
            btn1.PerformClick()
        Case Keys.NumPad2
            btn2.PerformClick()
    End Sub
```